# Polylint and linked bower packages

Tags: polymer

When using polylint with a linked bower packages (to ease local development), polylint throws an error. Ate there plans to support this?

When using polylint with a linked bower packages (to ease local development), polylint throws an error. Ate there plans to support this?

```
C:\git\gxi\poc\manager-app>polymer lint --input src\my-view1.html
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
    at Object.nodeWalkPrior (C:\User\danielm\progs\node\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\dom5\dom5.js:358:22)
    at C:\User\danielm\progs\node\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\polylint\lib\linters.js:471:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at domModuleAfterPolymer (C:\User\danielm\progs\node\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\polylint\lib\linters.js:454:23)
    at C:\User\danielm\progs\node\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\polylint\polylint.js:42:22
    at run (C:\User\danielm\progs\node\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:87:22)
    at C:\User\danielm\progs\node\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:100:28
    at flush (C:\User\danielm\progs\node\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\core-js\modules\_microtask.js:18:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```